# Does a "get which Google groups I'm in" endpoint exist in the Google APIs?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on an application that uses the Google Drive API and needs to match up Google groups and file permissions for authorization purposes. I noticed that in the `permissions/list` endpoint, you're able to get back the permission IDs of users, groups, or domains that have access to a given file. Does there exist any sort of Google API endpoint that could be used to get the permission IDs of all Google groups a user is currently a member of?

Comment: Does this what you mean [Retrieve all groups for a member](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_member_groups)?